# Get dimensions of an IMG dynamically in load event

Tags: jquery

Dimension of the `11.jpg` is not `100*100`, but I want to get real dimension of the image in load event. How could I do it?

```
<img id="t" src="img/11.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" />

$('#t').load(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't necessarily know that this is the *best* way, or if you need the inner `img.onload` per se, but you could use an `Image` object to get the `img` without the `width` and `height` attributes.

```
$('#t').load(function() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = this.src;

    img.onload = function(){
        console.log(img.width);
        console.log(img.height);
    };
});
```

Demo (have your console open): http://jsfiddle.net/ZgKGG/1/ Note, the attributes on the `img` tag give it `100x100` dimensions, but the image is actually `128x128`.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Widht :" + $("#t").width() + "\nHeight :" + $("#t").height());    
});​
```

Using plain javaScript

```
var imgObj = document.getElementById("t");
 alert("Widht :" + imgObj.width + "\nHeight :" + imgObj.height);
```

Please remove height and width if you want to use jQuery way. Your html should be,

```
<img id="t" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8953449b7b29d04cb89adaf912d84980?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" />
```

Try this working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U2Qcg/3/)

Comment: Note, the `width="100px" height="100px"` is probably important to pay attention to. When I add it to the `img` tag, I get [`100`, not 32](http://jsfiddle.net/U2Qcg/1/).

Comment: That's true, jquery will return the styled values if available else actual size.

Comment: That doesn't make any difference either? http://jsfiddle.net/ZgKGG/2/ Your example and fiddle still does not have the width and height attributes, as in here: http://jsfiddle.net/U2Qcg/2/

Comment: Sorry added link too early. please try this http://jsfiddle.net/U2Qcg/3/. In all case you have to remove the height and width of the image

Comment: Still you can change the height and width of image using javaScirpt or jquery. I can show you that code also

Comment: You seem to be missing the point; the `width` and `height` attributes *in the markup itself* is the problem. Changing the dimensions to whatever doesn't solve the problem of getting the `img` element's *actual* height and width.

Comment: That's true, and this is my solution to the problem so that developer can set that after getting actual attributes.